# How to detect the key press with keyDown on mac (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am writing a keyDown in viewcontroller.m but it does not work.

This is my code:

```
-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder{
  return YES;
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event{
  NSLog(@"%hu",event.keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You always receive keyDown & mouseDown events in NSView class not in NSViewController class.**

Create a subclass of NSView class, say it TestView and change default class of embedded NSView of NSViewController in Storyboard/Xib to TestView.

Also, it is always recommended to forward events to superclass especially one which you don't want to handle.

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%hu",event.keyCode);

    [super keyDown:event];
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner, how do I create a NSView class?

Comment: 1. Use Xcode File menu -> New -> File ... option. Else use Command + N keyboard shortcut to add a new file to source. Then, select "macOS" and "Cocoa Class" under Source and press "Next". Now, change default class from NSObject to NSView, Language to "Objective-C" and press Next to add this class to your view.